# Counting nr of elements in a file

Tags: xquery

I am trying to count the number of Harbour elements in an XML file. However, i keep getting the following error:

```
item expected, sequence found: (element harbour {...}, ...)
```

The code snippet is the following:

```
for $harbour in distinct-values(/VOC/voyage/leftpage/harbour)
let $count := count(/VOC/voyage/leftpage/harbour eq $harbour)
return concat($harbour, " ", $count)
```

Input XML:

```
<voyage> 
  <number>4411</number> 
  <leftpage> 
    <harbour>Rammekens</harbour> 
  </leftpage> 
</voyage> 
<voyage> 
  <number>4412</number> 
  <leftpage> 
    <harbour>Texel</harbour> 
  </leftpage> 
</voyage>
```

Can someone help me out? How do I iterate over the number of harbours in the XML file instead of trying to use `/VOC/voyage/leftpage/harbour`?

Answer (score 1):

`eq` is a value comparison, i.e. used to compare individual items. That is why the errors messages tells you that it is expecting a (single) item, but instead found all the harbour elements. You have to use the general comparison operator `=`. Also, when you would compare it like that

```
/VOC/voyage/leftpage/harbour = $harbour
```

it would always be 1 as it will compare the existence. instead, you want to filter out all `harbour` items which have an equal text element as child. You can do so using `[]`. All together it will be

```
for $harbour in distinct-values(/VOC/voyage/leftpage/harbour)
let $count := count(/VOC/voyage/leftpage/harbour[. = $harbour])
return concat($harbour, " ", $count)
```

Also, if your XQuery processor supports XQuery 3.0 you can also use a `group by` operator, which in my opinion is nicer to read (and could be faster, but this depends on the implementation):

```
for $voyage in /VOC/voyage
let $harbour := $voyage/leftpage/harbour
let $harbour-name := $harbour/string()
group by $harbour-name
return $harbour-name || " " || count($harbour)
```

Comment: Thnx for your quick response, I am trying to count the number of times a harbour is present in an XML file. So, for each harbour, i would like to know how many times it occurs in this XML file.

Comment: So what constitutes a different harbour in your input? Do they have different names oder ids or something? It would be useful if you would include a small snippet of your input XML,

Comment: A sample snippet looks like the following:
<voyage>
    <number>4411</number>
   
    <leftpage>
      <harbour>Rammekens</harbour>
    </leftpage>
   
  </voyage>
  <voyage>
    <number>4412</number>
    
    <leftpage>
      <harbour>Texel</harbour>
    </leftpage>
    
 </voyage>

I am trying to iterate over all the Harbours in order to see how many times a harbour is present.

Comment: @Paul, both of Dirk's suggestions should give the distinct counts. In a declarative language like XQuery you don't have to "iterate", you simply write expressions that select or compute the result. And the suggested snippepts do that.